# How to measure elapsed time using MSP430

Tags: msp430

What I want to do is measure the time it takes for a blade to spin round driven by a motor, and I am trying to achieve this using an LDR which detects the change in light each time the blade rotates over it (if there is a better method then please share). Once the ADC value from the LDR reaches a low enough threshold due to the shadow cast by the blade, I would like to register that as 1 rotation, and effectively measure the time between rotations.

I'm aware this can be achieved using Timer_A, although I don't know which mode to select (Up, Up/Down, Continuous), whether to divide the clock and most importantly how to **store the time as a variable in milliseconds*. So it would look something like..

```
If (ADC_value <900) {            // if one rotation made 
  Time taken to rotate = X milliseconds
}
```

How can I obtain X?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your LDR a Cadmium Sulfide sensor? If yes, these are typically too slow for this type of application, you should use a photo-diode.

Comment: Have you compared the ADC conversion time to the estimated elapsed time that you are measuring? If the ADC time is not relatively small, you should convert your light input to digital via hardware first.

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off conditioning the input for a digital input (as implied by Mattman944) and then using the input capture function, which is a hardware peripheral in the micro which, depending on the frequency of the event of interest, can be set up to either measure the number of transitions in a period of time, or the time (timer ticks) between transitions.  Either measure will give you a way to compute the frequency of the event.

The advantage of this approach is that the timing measurement doesn't depend on the conversion time of the ADC, instruction cycle time for comparison logic code, or time time it takes to get into an interrupt service routine.

There's plenty of information about input capture out there, including specifically for the MSP430.  Google is very helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

In Up or Up/Down mode, you would need a specific value for CCR0. The only mode that makes sense is Continuous.

To measure the length of an interval, read the current timer value (TAxR) both at the start and the end of the interval, then subtract them. This gives you the number of ticks, which you can convert into milliseconds if you know the number of ticks per seconds.

You run into problems when the interval is longer than 2<sup>16</sup> ticks. If that is possible, you can increase the length of a tick by dividing the clock source down.

Comment: It is usually better to handle the rollover, than avoid it.